# graphite or grafana, rename IDs to String in the series

Tags: graphite, grafana

I've a data series that contains ID of the users. I can print the chart for 1,2,3 where the number are the IDs of the user. Now, i've in a file the name of the users and their IDs, thus 1=Alice, 2=Bob etc. 
Is there a way to rename the series such that the chart show Alice or Bob instead of numbers?

Note that I user *, I've a data series of this type request. where as USER-ID i put * and graphite+grafana shows the 3 charts, one for each USER-ID.

This is what I get, and I would like to have for each series the name of the user instead of the ID (which is half covered for security)

[image]

Comment: Don't think you can map IDs using a file. Guess next best option would be to submit your metrics **by username** in the first place. Then you will naturally have them on graphs as well.

Comment: the fact is that I can't do that. I'm fine also adding a bunch of alias command, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: With aliases it would be something like `aliasSub(aliasSub(timeSeries,"users.1.req$","users.usernameOfID1here.req"),"users.2.req$","users.usernameOfID2here.req")`. Though it will hit a function length limit at some point, and might add some overhead.

Comment: that's not feasible, i was thinking that they may have a system to  passa  dictionary with key the number that it's displayed and as value the string that i want to display for that. such as `[{"4121..","bob},{....}]` . wondering if this is so complicated, in the end is just replacing a string when rendering the chart. no?